# how to reuse svg like a component

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have 5 stars rating on my page

I need to reuse my SVG as a component

how it's possible?

```
<div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-star-fill bg-golden" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z"/>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-star-fill bg-golden" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z"/>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-star" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M2.866 14.85c-.078.444.36.791.746.593l4.39-2.256 4.389 2.256c.386.198.824-.149.746-.592l-.83-4.73 3.522-3.356c.33-.314.16-.888-.282-.95l-4.898-.696L8.465.792a.513.513 0 0 0-.927 0L5.354 5.12l-4.898.696c-.441.062-.612.636-.283.95l3.523 3.356-.83 4.73zm4.905-2.767-3.686 1.894.694-3.957a.565.565 0 0 0-.163-.505L1.71 6.745l4.052-.576a.525.525 0 0 0 .393-.288L8 2.223l1.847 3.658a.525.525 0 0 0 .393.288l4.052.575-2.906 2.77a.565.565 0 0 0-.163.506l.694 3.957-3.686-1.894a.503.503 0 0 0-.461 0z"/>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-star" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M2.866 14.85c-.078.444.36.791.746.593l4.39-2.256 4.389 2.256c.386.198.824-.149.746-.592l-.83-4.73 3.522-3.356c.33-.314.16-.888-.282-.95l-4.898-.696L8.465.792a.513.513 0 0 0-.927 0L5.354 5.12l-4.898.696c-.441.062-.612.636-.283.95l3.523 3.356-.83 4.73zm4.905-2.767-3.686 1.894.694-3.957a.565.565 0 0 0-.163-.505L1.71 6.745l4.052-.576a.525.525 0 0 0 .393-.288L8 2.223l1.847 3.658a.525.525 0 0 0 .393.288l4.052.575-2.906 2.77a.565.565 0 0 0-.163.506l.694 3.957-3.686-1.894a.503.503 0 0 0-.461 0z"/>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-star" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M2.866 14.85c-.078.444.36.791.746.593l4.39-2.256 4.389 2.256c.386.198.824-.149.746-.592l-.83-4.73 3.522-3.356c.33-.314.16-.888-.282-.95l-4.898-.696L8.465.792a.513.513 0 0 0-.927 0L5.354 5.12l-4.898.696c-.441.062-.612.636-.283.95l3.523 3.356-.83 4.73zm4.905-2.767-3.686 1.894.694-3.957a.565.565 0 0 0-.163-.505L1.71 6.745l4.052-.576a.525.525 0 0 0 .393-.288L8 2.223l1.847 3.658a.525.525 0 0 0 .393.288l4.052.575-2.906 2.77a.565.565 0 0 0-.163.506l.694 3.957-3.686-1.894a.503.503 0 0 0-.461 0z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add your .svg file in your project folder, and then add a relative path in your .html file inside  tag src.

```
<div>
    <img src="../mysvg.svg"/>
    <img src="../mysvg.svg"/>
    <img src="../mysvg.svg"/>
    <img src="../mysvg.svg"/>
    <img src="../mysvg.svg"/>
</div>
```

Of course this is just in case you do not need inline svg-s. You can also check  tag for svg-s.